How to handle URLs outside of the build system in Vite?
I'm migrating a Vue.js app from Vue CLI to the Vite build system.
We have a web service implementing an API and dynamic content. In production we handle this with a reverse-proxy that routes /api/** to the backend and the rest to a static files web server.
With Vue CLI we hooked in the dev web server to do something similar: requests to /api would go to the local dev backend, to a test environment, or just return mock values depending on the configuration.
I've had no trouble replicating this with Vite dev server, through the configureServer hook.
The issue is that, apparently, Vite insists on trying to build /api paths and obviously fails with:
[vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "/api/icon.png" from "src/stuff.vue". Does the file exist?

I have tried a few thing in vite.config.js:

assetsInclude: ['/api/icon.png'] (or regexp)

build: { rollupOptions: { external: ['/api/logo.png'] } } (or regexp)

this following plugin which kind of works but it seems a bit complicated and I'm afraid it might break the production build:
    {
        name: 'ignore-back',
        enforce: 'pre',
        resolveId: {
            order: 'pre',
            handler(source, importer, options) {
                if(source.startsWith('/api/')) return {
                    id: 'API',
                    external: true
                };
                return null;
            }
        },
        load: {
            order: 'pre',
            handler(id) {
                if(id == 'API') return '';
                return null;
            }
        }
    }



I looked at different sections of the Vite documentation, and here at SO, and did not find a solution. Obviously a web app calling its backend does not seem like a corner-case, so I must be missing something.

It's not shown where  "/api/icon.png" occurs. If it's processed from src attr then it makes sense to prevent this from being done as this isn't regular behavior for html. The 'ignore-back' way makes sense. You can also make :src= dynamic to prevent this
